# How to prevent game client version spoofing

Tags: networking

Basically I have a c++ server that will use a binary protocol to talk to my client (unity game). As part of the login process I want to send the client version to the server. The server then responds saying (assuming login credentials are correct) they are okay to connect, or if the client version is outdated it returns a client version outdated.

My question is, how can I prevent people using old client versions and spoofing as the latest version. As this could potentially lead to server bugs as it is handling an outdated client thinking it is up to date...

Thank you :)

Comment: Consideró this, if they spoof their own client version, they are the ones risking issues on their own characters and general gameplay. Your job is to make sure that no unintended changes are possible on the server side by this. But if they send garbage data then you might as well send them garbage data back as a penalty to them. Once an executable is in the hands of people they can do whatever they want with it. There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: This isn't possible, the client has _full control_ over anything that comes from their computer (some things are really hard to break but infeasible to implement unless you're a corporation that can throw money at stuff like that). Best solution is to just error check all the netcode that comes from the client and if stuff doesn't meet stringent requirements, you disconnect them or tell them to update or something.